# where do i define shared dependencies in gradle 8 structure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

[image: Current build logic structure]

The above is my current build logic structure, when I try to apply shared dependencies in `java-common-conventions.gradle` the build complains.

also I'm unable to apply spring boot plugins like so:

```
    // Apply the java Plugin to add support for Java.
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
}
```

error:
`Invalid plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.7.10']. Plugin requests from precompiled scripts must not include a version number. Please remove the version from the offending request and make sure the module containing the requested plugin 'org.springframework.boot' is an implementation dependency`
it does work if I define it in every subproject's `build.gradle`

how do I shared dependencies and how/where do I define the `subproject` & allproject closures?

Comment: What are the contents for the `build-logic/build.gradle`? And how are you applying the convention plugins to a project? Amend your question with those details.